# Woocommerce multiple products to cart with one click

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to know how i can add more than one product with one button click. For example when product 1 is selected automatically add product 2 with it. I thought it would be possible with the woocommerce add to cart query string.

```
?add-to-cart=117
```

Would like to have a query that also adds 118 to it. Is that possible?

```
?add-to-cart=117&&118
```

Or is there another solution for this problem?

Comment: Have you tried `?add-to-cart=117&add-to-cart=118` ?

Comment: check out here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42570982/adding-multiple-items-to-woocommerce-cart-at-once

Comment: @Rameleu it only adds the 1st one

Comment: Well then check @Anand's answer

Comment: @AnandChoudhary Thank you this worked :)