# Woocommerce redirect to cart with already added products

Tags: javascript, c#, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a specific problem that includes WordPress, Woocommerce, and c#.

My C# application allows users to access products from the Woocommerce shop. After selecting some products, the user has an option to send the order to his email, to see if everything is ok. At the bottom of the email, I want to add a "Go to cart" button.

This button should redirect the user to the cart/checkout page, with already added products. In order to do it, I need to have a specific link. I know that there is a method to add one product, but in this case, I need to direct the user to a cart full of different products and quantities. I am wondering if there is a method of doing it in javascript (the button that executes multiple links and the opens cart full of products).

Alternatively, I can create this cart earlier, when the mail is sent, and add a button that opens a specific session. However, I don't have any idea how to do it, and how to maintain this session for, for example, 3 days.

I don't know what code should be helpful here, so I don't post any. If you think that you need some of my code, write a comment and I will update the post.

I know that there is a code that you can paste into WordPress which allows you to add various products in one link, however, because of the specificity of this application (client shall not edit any WordPress files), I can't do it.

Do you have any ideas about how to resolve it?

Comment: stack overflow is for help with programming questions and you are more likely to get help if you show us the code, or at least make an attempt. stack overflow guidelines say that you should be posting a minimal reproducible example. please add one.

Answer (score 0):

By default woocommerce you can add one product at a time through the url:
... cart /? add-to-cart = 12

By default without changing anything in WOcommerce you will not be able through a button to add these products all at once, you will need to change the default code.

A simple solution would be to create a wordpress plugin that adds this functionality of accepting to add multiple products via url and the client just adds this wordpress plugin and it will be working.

I advise you to create a local environment to test before production.

Documentation Link: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/

Here is a code example, you will need to create a folder inside the plugins folder and give it a name example: my_plugin first and inside it a file called my_plugin.php

Inside this file you add the following code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: YOUR PLUGIN NAME
*/

function woocommerce_maybe_add_multiple_products_to_cart() {
// Make sure WC is installed, and add-to-cart qauery arg exists, and contains at least one comma.
if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Form_Handler' ) || empty( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) || false === strpos( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'], ',' ) ) {
    return;
}

// Remove WooCommerce's hook, as it's useless (doesn't handle multiple products).
remove_action( 'wp_loaded', array( 'WC_Form_Handler', 'add_to_cart_action' ), 20 );

$product_ids = explode( ',', $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] );
$count       = count( $product_ids );
$number      = 0;

foreach ( $product_ids as $product_id ) {
    if ( ++$number === $count ) {
        // Ok, final item, let's send it back to woocommerce's add_to_cart_action method for handling.
        $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] = $product_id;

        return WC_Form_Handler::add_to_cart_action();
    }

    $product_id        = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint( $product_id ) );
    $was_added_to_cart = false;
    $adding_to_cart    = wc_get_product( $product_id );

    if ( ! $adding_to_cart ) {
        continue;
    }

    $add_to_cart_handler = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_handler', $adding_to_cart->product_type, $adding_to_cart );

    /*
     * Sorry.. if you want non-simple products, you're on your own.
     *
     * Related: WooCommerce has set the following methods as private:
     * WC_Form_Handler::add_to_cart_handler_variable(),
     * WC_Form_Handler::add_to_cart_handler_grouped(),
     * WC_Form_Handler::add_to_cart_handler_simple()
     *
     * Why you gotta be like that WooCommerce?
     */
    if ( 'simple' !== $add_to_cart_handler ) {
        continue;
    }

    // For now, quantity applies to all products.. This could be changed easily enough, but I didn't need this feature.
    $quantity          = empty( $_REQUEST['quantity'] ) ? 1 : wc_stock_amount( $_REQUEST['quantity'] );
    $passed_validation = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $product_id, $quantity );

    if ( $passed_validation && false !== WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity ) ) {
        wc_add_to_cart_message( array( $product_id => $quantity ), true );
    }
}
}

 // Fire before the WC_Form_Handler::add_to_cart_action callback.
 add_action( 'wp_loaded',        'woocommerce_maybe_add_multiple_products_to_cart', 15 );
```

One important thing, this code is just an example and you can add products from a url like this: `http://shop.com/shop/cart/?add-to-cart=3001,3282` just passing the product ids you want to update.

This code that modifies woocommerce and thus allowing various products by url, was not developed by me I took it as an example in the link below: 
[Adding multiple items to WooCommerce cart at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42570982/adding-multiple-items-to-woocommerce-cart-at-once)

In this link you will see several suggestions. What I did was just give a light that might help solve your problem.
Developing a plugin that will not change the source code of the client site is the best option and if something goes wrong or fails just disable everything back to normal;)
I hope I helped in some way.