# WooCommerce: create an order by using a form on a static site

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a product landing page that is hosted on a static site (due to various reasons we can't have it created in WordPress). I want to redirect users to the WooCommerce checkout page when they click Buy on this page.

The page consists of a few checkboxes and radio buttons, which are essentially options for a few different products. So, when customer clicks Buy, the WooCommerce cart should contain those products with selected options.

I've created those products in WooCommerce. I've looked at the 'add to cart' URL feature. This option would require a different URL for every possible combination of selected options on the landing page.

Is there a way to have just one URL in the form action attribute on the landing page, and have it send all the information to WooCommerce? And how could that information be used in WooCommerce to add those products to the cart?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the product ID for the product and link the button on your landing page directly to your Woocommerce store itself.

Example:

You have a store called 'Productstore' on https://productstore.com. By adding a button on your product landingpage with the href="https://productstore.com/cart/?add-to-cart=ID" you can redirect to the product being added to the cart of your store. You just need to add the ID (product id) to the URL. If you want to redirect them to checkout (or any other page) you can change the '/cart/' to checkout, https://productstore.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=1.

To add multiple products to the cart, you can use quantity in the URL like so: https://productstore.com/?add-to-cart=14601&quantity=5.

Im not sure if it is possible to add multiple products with one link, but following this post you might be able to achieve it: https://dsgnwrks.pro/snippets/woocommerce-allow-adding-multiple-products-to-the-cart-via-the-add-to-cart-query-string/

For more information, I used this source: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-custom-add-cart-urls-ultimate-guide/.

/** EDIT **
[Adding multiple items to WooCommerce cart at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42570982/adding-multiple-items-to-woocommerce-cart-at-once) - seems to have worked for OP.

Comment: Yeah, I've looked at that, and it works for only one product. But this page will have a few products, and a user can select 1 or more of them. I have an idea of how to implement it by generating that add-to-cart link programmatically.
I was wondering if I could have just one link that doesn't change, actually a form submit button, that can send necessary information to WooCommerce, and then have the cart get populated based on the received information?

Comment: Are there going to be product variations included in this form?

_The page consists of a few checkboxes and radio buttons, which are essentially options for a few different products._

Specify 'options'.

Comment: Yes, they represent variations. Checkboxes are for variations like T-shirt size (S, M, L), since customer can choose the same T-shirt in different sizes, and radio buttons are also used for variable product, but we only allow one of them to be selected.

Comment: Okay, well you for sure will need to firstly write some logic concerning the variations, luckily you have variation id's so you probably will just need a switch / if statement for that.

*edit, I keep forgetting the enter key publishes my comment. *

For getting the products into WooCommerce itself, the only way I would know how to (and have implementen before, ages ago) is to have a custom page, and use a get statement to get the list of id's out of the URL.

Comment: Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42570982/adding-multiple-items-to-woocommerce-cart-at-once) help you any further? To generate those id's in the URL you probably can just use Jquery/Javascript to edit the form action with the id's you get out of your logic.

Comment: Yes, that does help. There's a solution in that thread that works with variable products. I'm using JavaScript to check which checkboxes are checked, and use their values to create a URL to which the form is submitted. FYI, the form method must be post, not get. It's working fine, except when I have 10 or more products selected. In that case, I get a 502 error. :/

Comment: _FYI, the form method must be post, not get_ - Yes, not sure how I edit my comments as the pencil is not working, but indeed. And for the 502 error, probably server side because it cannot handle the actions it has to perform. Could turn on WB_DEBUG and check if there are any PHP errors being logged.