# How to create smart bundle product in wordpress woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

[image: Desired product display]

This is my desired output. I tried various ways but I could not able to do it. Please help me. How to do it and what extension and steps needed for it?

**Thank you in advance.**

**WHAT I NEED:**

1. I want a bundle product display as shown in the figure.
2. Product XYZ is a variable product (?) that has a number of products and different prices.
3. Installation for XYZ - single product - the quantity of this product should be automatically changed to whatever quantities selected for Product XYZ.
4. Product X - variable product (?) - this is dynamic - whatever product select in Product XYZ then it dynamically list-out products for that.
   For example:
   suppose "Product XYZ" has P1, P2 ....... P10
   "Product X" has P1X1, P1X2, ....... P10X1, P10X2 ......
   When Product XYZ ==> P1 then
   Product X shows P1X1 ...... P1Xn
5. Finally Add to Quote.

**WHAT I DID:**
I tried variable product, YITH Bundled product, YITH Add to Quote and simple product to create bundle product display. I able to create product bundle page having dropdown options (eg. Product X). But nont as desired output.

**WHAT I DO NOT ABLE To Do:**

1. Automatic installation quatitiy.
2. Dynamic Product X dropdown list - this will generated after First product is selected.

Comment: This paid plugin might be able to do that. I'm not sure. Check its specs. https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-dynamic-pricing-discounts/7119279

Answer (score 1):

> How to do it and what extension and steps needed for it?

**I think you're going at it the wrong way.** When you think about it, you just want to add multiples products at the same time to your user cart.

By default, woocommerce doesn't offer such function, but a bunch of people already worked on it.
Just take a look at one of these links bellow:

[Adding multiple items to WooCommerce cart at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42570982/adding-multiple-items-to-woocommerce-cart-at-once).
[Add multiple products to cart from URL link in WooCommerce](https://gist.github.com/lukecav/ab9dbdee88de686ce6b59c264cde8970).
[WooCommerce: Allow adding multiple products to the cart via the add-to-cart query string](https://dsgnwrks.pro/snippets/woocommerce-allow-adding-multiple-products-to-the-cart-via-the-add-to-cart-query-string/).

As describe, you will be able to add multiple product at the same time using a simple url `cart/?add-to-cart=3001,3282` which is pretty much what bundles are.

Comment: I don't know you understand my question or not. I am using the premium version of the YITH bundle and add to the Quote extension. **I don't need to add products to CART.**  I successfully created a bundle product that has multiple single, variable products. My issue is different. How to automatically set the same quantity for the 2nd product by comparing the 1st product. And, How to dynamically generate sub-category products(3rd product) by checking 1st product.

Comment: Example: let's assume I want to sell a Table, Chair, etc. So, a customer wants to buy 10 sets of Tables. 2nd product is an installation of the table which is a fixed price(for all) for each quantity. Then the 3rd product is (kind of) sub-categories which is only applicable to parent (1st) product. e.g. chair selected => 3rd product will be chair mat, chair cushion. Here, the customer selected the table on 1st product then 3rd product will be a table mat, waterproof table protector, etc.

Comment: So, the final look will be:: Table 10  $1500, Installation 10 $150, Table Mat 1 100